# CodeIgniter 4 with hmvc

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4, hmvc

I'm trying to work with HMVC in CodeIgniter 4. I worked with it previously but in version 3.10. I can't find the HMVC plugin for CI4.

Somebody can help me? Thanks.

I want to work with modules for each class and add their respective views and controllers.

Comment: Could you please tell if you used to work with a specific hmvc library/tool?

Comment: I can't say with certainty because they never told me what bookstore it was, they only showed me in a company

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question is a little too wide to give you any precise help.

That said, I suggest you to read this complete [**CodeIgniter4 HMVC Programming tutorial**](https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/codeigniter-4-hmvc-programming/?utm_content=cmp-true), which is also recommended in a [thread on the official CI4 forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-78889.html).

If you feel comfortable with it, you can then look at this [CodeIgniter4-HMVC Project Starter](https://github.com/Simpletine/CodeIgniter-4-HMVC).